# Google user consent page

Tags: google-oauth

I'm using `passport-google-oauth` module in *node.js* for user authentication in a web app. When a google account is already logged in in a browser and you try to login to the web app via google, `passport-google-oauth` automatically redirects to the web app as if it has already been authorized and without the google user consent page.

How do I force display of google user consent page every time user logs in via google. I've added `approval_prompt` but it's still not working.

Please shed some light.

Updates:

authController.js

```
passport.authenticate('google', { scope : ['profile', 'email'] },
            function (err, user) {
                req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                    if (err) 
                    {
                        console.log(err);
                        return res.view('site/index',{callouts:callouts.wrongAccess});
                    }


                    return res.redirect('/');
                });
            })(req, res);
     },
```

passport.js

```
passport.use(new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID        : configAuth.googleAuth.clientID,
        clientSecret    : configAuth.googleAuth.clientSecret,
        callbackURL     : configAuth.googleAuth.callbackURL,
        },
        function (token, refreshToken, profile, done) {
  process.nextTick(function() {
    var newUser = {};
    var name    = {};
    var email   = profile.emails[0].value;

    User.findOne({'email':email}, function (err, user) {
      if (err)
      {
        return done(err);
      }
      if (user) 
      {
        return done(null, user);
      } else 
      {
        User.create(newUser).done(function (err, created){
          console.log(created, 'done');
          if (err)
          {
            throw err;
          }
          return done(null, created);
        });
      }
    });
  });
}));
```

Comment: It should work, could you show more details including some code or request?

Comment: Hi owen, thanks for your response. I've updated the question above and added the code that i was using. Hope you can help me with this